# Disable running some xunit tests in Visual Studio (by Resharper)

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, resharper, xunit

I have some Integration Tests (very long running). If they are in main solution and I choose to run all tests these tests are also picked up. 
How to avoid it?

These tests are suppose to be running from scripts on CI. Traits does not help (AFAIK) cause R# also picks them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question indirectly gave the answer: [resharper test runner - how to execute by category?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28785830/resharper-test-runner-how-to-execute-by-category)

In **xUnit**:
You add a Trait:

```
[Trait("Category", "LongRunning")]
[Fact]
public void Test()
{
}
```

In "ReSharper->Options->Unit Testing" you need to exclude category "LongRunning":

[image: P]

PS, when saving this change you probably want to save it to "team-shared" layer so your team have it the same way.

Answer (score 1):

Use different playlists in resharper, or run different traits (Test Explorer). [In Visual Studio Test, how to make a playlist which automatically excludes certain tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293990/in-visual-studio-test-how-to-make-a-playlist-which-automatically-excludes-certa/19399035#19399035)

Comment: I am bound to R#, and this solution will work only in VS Test, but I will give a try later.

Comment: Thanks, although it didn't gave solution, your answer gave me the idea what should I be looking (googling) for.